# Solid angle subtended by a tilted surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, integration, mathematics

I want to compute the solid angle subtended by the surface

$$\begin{pmatrix}
u\\ 
v\\ 
r
\end{pmatrix},\quad -1\leq u\leq 1, \quad -1\leq v \leq 1$$
tilted by an angle $\theta$ from to the $z$ axis, with respect to an observer located at the origin.

See image for illustration.
[image: tilted surface]

I am reading Robert Boyd's [Radiometry and the Detection of Optical Radiation](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=tzRRAAAAMAAJ), where it is said that such a surface element subtends a solid angle given by
$$\mathrm{d}\Omega=\frac{\text{d}A \cos\theta}{r^2}. \label{1} \tag{1}$$I want to make sure I understand this formula.

Using the general formula for a solid angle given in [Zangwill §3.4](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=tEYSUegp9WYC),
$$\Omega=\iint_S \frac{\mathbf{r\cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}}}{\mathbf{r}^3}\text{d}S,$$
I arrived at the result

$$\Omega=2\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sec\theta-r\tan\theta}{r\sqrt{r^{2}+2-2r\sin\theta}}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sec\theta+r\tan\theta}{r\sqrt{r^{2}+2+2r\sin\theta}}\right)\right). \label{2} \tag{2}$$

For $\theta=0$ this gives the simpler expression for the not-tilted surface,
$$\Omega=4 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{r \sqrt{r^2+2}}\right).$$

I have spent some good amount of time arriving at $\ref{2}$, by computing the projection of a surface element on the observation vector and performing the double integral. I wonder if there is an easier way to do it.

Besides that, I don't see any simple $\cos \theta$ term in $\ref{2}$, as suggested by $\ref{1}$. Can anyone show me how to (wisely) use this formula?

Comment: How about ${\mathbf r}\cdot\hat{\mathbf n}= r\cos\theta$ and then writing the Zangwill formula in differential instead of integral form? I suppose $dA=dS\,.$

Comment: I think there is no easier way to reach the answer. It will involve an integration. And for the shape you have, I don't think there is a shortcut for completing the integration.

Comment: Are you asking why the final answer doesn't have a $\cos \theta$ term? It shouldn't have such a term. An infinitesimal part of the surface does have such a term, where $\theta$ is the angle between the normal vector and the vector pointing from the origin. But since you have a finite surface this angle changes because, even though the normal direction is unchanged the vector from the origin keeps changing. The integral of a changing cosine term isn't a cosine term, so your final answer doesn't have an obvious cosine term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of solid angle from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Definition_and_properties

is $\Omega = \frac{A}{r^2}$

For small areas with the surface perpendicular to the radius

$d\Omega = \frac{dA}{r^2}$

and the $\cos\theta$ term, in your formula 1) is just to do with the angle of tilt - just as the height of a stick of length $L$, tilted by angle $\theta$ to the vertical, is $L\cos\theta$.